# jQuery and Using Enter Key on Button Element Instead of / As well as Spacebar

Tags: jquery

On my forms I prevent the user from submitting the form by clicking enter in text elements however, I want to allow them to use the enter key to submit the form when the button element has focus.  Currently, it only works with the spacebar.  I've tried the following:

```
$("#dyn-gen-form").on("keypress", "#genAttFormBtn", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  log("pressed a key");
  var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (k == 13) {
    // do the work
    return false;
  }
});
```

But it isn't working.  By isn't working, I mean, the event isn't triggered. I get nothing.

Comment: I think `$("#dyn-gen-form")` is the form itself. Try to give it as `$("#dyn-gen-form #submit")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a sample for you: http://jsfiddle.net/p7vzJ/54/ - button detects spacebar as well as enter key stroke; **Please press space or enter after the jsfiddle is loaded.**

I can remove my post if you don't wanna use `.live` Please let me know.

**JQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#genAttFormBtn").focus();
$("#dyn-gen-form").live("keydown", "#genAttFormBtn", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //log("pressed a key");
    if(e.keyCode == 32) {
        alert('whitespace');
        $("#previous").click();
    } else if(e.keyCode == 13) {
       alert('enter');
    }
});

});​
```

cheers!

Comment: This works in your jsfiddle example, but for some reason, it still isn't working in my app. I'll come back with more info if I find the issue.

Comment: Saweet, Sure, I would love to nail this down before I sleep :)) itching now :P cheers.

Comment: Brooooooo :) lol, it happens, all good; have a good one. cheers!